# Can I insert correctly into an alphabetically sorted list in O(n)?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I'm trying to get the runtime down from O(nlgn) to O(n). Right now, I append a new Person object to the address book and then sort, but I'd rather just insert the new Person object at the right place alphabetically. What's the best way to do this?

```
// Swift 4.2
class Person {
    var fName: String
    var lName: String
    init(fName: String, lName: String) {
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
    }
}

var addressBook = [Person]()

var peopleToAdd: [Person] = [Person(fName: "John", lName: "Smith"),
                        Person(fName: "Joan", lName: "Smith"),
                        Person(fName: "Rick", lName: "Smith"),
                        Person(fName: "Adam", lName: "Beyers"),
                        Person(fName: "Alan", lName: "Beyers"),
                        Person(fName: "Nick", lName: "Johnson"),
                        Person(fName: "Dan", lName: "Johnson")].shuffled()

for person in peopleToAdd {
    addNewPersonAlphabetically(person: person)
}

func addNewPersonAlphabetically(person: Person) {
    // this is where the magic happens!
}


print(addressBook) // Should print an alphabetized list of Person objects
```

If 2 last names are the same, then go by first name.

Forgive me if I'm asking an already-answered question: I tried searching but most answers just resorted to sorting.

Thanks!

Comment: Implement binary search to find the correct index to insert into, and insert into that. The run time will be `O(logn) + O(n)` = `O(n)`

Comment: Well, you do have to extend the array. Then move everything from the insertion point to the end down one space, and insert the new item.

Comment: Adding a new element to the end of the list and then **bubbling it down** until it's in place is O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the help! If anyone would like to write up one of these solutions, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer :)

Comment: You want `addressBook` to be a sorted array? [This](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/02/sorted-array/) would be helpful. [Here](https://github.com/ole/SortedArray) is the implementation.

Comment: Yep, a sorted array. Equally important is the O(n) insertion of new elements to the correct position.